# Probability that arithmetic mean > 5.5 for a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A random variable is normally distributed with a mathematical expectation of $5$ and a variance of $9$. Find the probability that the arithmetic mean of $9$ values ​​of this random variable is $>5.5$.

I have no idea how this can be solved, I would be very happy if you could help.

Comment: What is the distribution of the sum of $9$ copies of your distribution?  It is normal with mean ___and variance ___.  Unlike most distributions, a sum of independent normals is again normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: A linear function of (independent) normal RVs has normal distribution. Find the expectation and the variance of the arithmetic mean, then you just look at the probability tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!